# How to make comma separated string from same values of dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have list of dict. which have same values for few keys. I want to make comma separated string of those keys,values which are common in the dictionary.

Input:

```
l = [{'name':'abc', 'role_no':30,'class':'class-2'},{'name':'abc','role_no':30, 'class':'class-3'},{'name':'mnp','role_no':31,'class':'class-4'}]
```

Output:

```
l=[{'name':'abc','role_no':30, 'class':'class-2, class3'}, {'name':'mnp','role_no':31,'class':'class-4'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code that gives you what you want:

```
l = [{'name':'abc', 'role_no':30, 'class':'class-2'},{'name':'abc', 'role_no':30, 'class':'class-3'}]

o = [{}] #output since you want a list of a dictionary

for i in l: #For each dictionary
    for j in i: #for each key in the dictionary
        if j not in o[0]: #if the value of the key is not in o
            o[0][j] = i[j] #add a new value to the output dictionary
        elif o[0][j]==i[j]: #if the value is in o and matches the value already there
            pass
        else: #if the value is in o and doesn't match the value already there
            o[0][j]+= ", " + (i[j]) #otherwise add it to the string of the value that is there

print(o) #[{'name': 'abc', 'role_no': 30, 'class': 'class-2, class-3'}]
```

Comment: Thanks. it works for only common dict. I have edited input (not working)